# What is better BigO log(m*n) or (m+n)?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

With `m` and `n` being the two dimensions of a 2D matrix, which search algorithms with givens Big-O are considered faster:

- `log(m*n)` or
- `(m+n)` or
- `log(m)*log(n)`?

Comment: Try applying some basic properties of logs.

Comment: can you plot some graphs, that might clarify things?

Comment: Remember that log(m*n) = log(m) + log(n) which should make it clear which is the fastest.

Comment: Those are functions, not search algorithms. Big-O of a function is a set of functions, which is still not a search algorithm. Please try harder to say what you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither one is "best" outside the context of a specific application. Remember that `O(f(x))` means that the time an algorithm takes to process an input of size `x` is *proportional* to `f(x)`, with no indication of what that proportion is. If you have one algorithm that is `O(n)` (i.e. linear), but there is a constant multiplicative factor of, say `10^4`, and a second algorithm that is `O(n^2)`, but only has a multiplicative factor of `1`, then the second algorithm is going to be better for problem sizes of up to `10^4`. If your actual problem domain is guaranteed to never have inputs with sizes exceeding `10^2`, there is no reason whatsoever that you would pick the first algorithm. This is admittedly an extreme example, but the point is that you need to know your problem domain and the inputs you expect to have to handle, as well as the different algorithms you are evaluating and the associated costs in order to pick the best algorithm for your program. There are a great many real-world situations, where picking the mathematically most efficient (for extremely large-scale problems) algorithm is not the right choice, and can actually cause performance issues, because your inputs are never large enough to realize the savings in efficiency that is theoretically possible.

In your specific case, the `O(log(m*n))` is definitely the most efficient as the size of your problems grow, but if you are never operating in the realm of larger problem sets, one of the others may in fact be "best" for your specific use.

Comment: Thanks, the answer like yours make SO a great place to ask questions.

Comment: O(f(x)) does not mean proportional to f(x). Theta(f(x)) is closer to that, but it still doesn't mean proportional to f(x), even asymptotically. I realize that many people in CS misuse big-O notation and often that is fine and doesn't cause problems, but when someone is confused it's a good idea to use something consistent with the formal definition.

Comment: @DouglasZare Yes, I suppose that was a bit sloppy definition-wise. The concept that two separate algorithms that are both `O(f(x))` will be proportional asymptotically would be somewhat more correct. I wasn't going for complete theoretical rigor in that answer...

Comment: Two algorithms that are both O(f(x)) do not need to be anything close to proportional asymptotically. n and n^2 are both O(2^n). Despite the common misuses, O(f(x)) does not mean cf(x) for some constant, it is an upper bound. If you want bounds above and below that differ by a constant, that's what Theta(f(x)) means. If you don't believe me, please look it up.

Answer (score 6):

Above reduced interpretations are as:

1. **O(log(m*n))** is equivalent to **O(log m + log n)**
2. **O(m+n)** and **O(log(m)*log(n))** are in reduced form itself

As logarithm of numbers are smaller than the number. Thus Order will be

**O(log(m*n)) < O(log(m)*log(n)) < O(m+n)**

That is log(m*n) is most efficient.

Remember it is a bigO. It would be better if you consider it for all possible output.

Answer (score 2):

The best is - `log(m*n)` (which is equivalent to `log(m) + log(n)`) 
Then - `log(m)*log(n)` 
And then - `m+n`

Answer (score 2):

Write the first one as `log m + log n`. This is clearly better than `m + n`. It's also better than `log(m) * log(n)`.

So the answer is `log (m * n)` is best.